# Access Denied When running FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I have just started working with FastAPI, but quickly hitting an issue. Tried running a sample code on the FastAPI website, but got access denied error.

I'm on Windows, and have access to the all the folders - so not sure why the error message.

I would appreciate if someone can help please, thanks.

I have included a link to the screenshot of the said error message along with the sample code..

[Error message image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NzOZ.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 107, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

````
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: float
    is_offer: Union[bool, None] = None


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "world"}

@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}

@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
def update_item(item_id: int, item: Item):
    return {"item_name": item.name, "item_id": item_id, "item_price": item.price}```
````

Comment: If you could, please copy and paste your code as text into the question. Code/text as a screenshot doesn't allow us to copy/paste and reproduce on our machines, which makes it harder to troubleshoot and more difficult to answer (since our answer would naturally have the same code, but with any necessary corrections).

Comment: Hello @bOB, you can try to use administrator mode to run the code or try and update your Python version. if this isn't working please respond to either one of us

Comment: @JNevill I have updated the post with the code as requested.

Answer (score 0):

In windows when opening CMD choose run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get permission errors if you're running fastAPI in reload mode and it doesn't have access to a directory under the root you're running from.